# How to display outcoming and incoming SOAP message for ZSI.ServiceProxy in Python?

Tags: python, web-services, zsi

How to display a SOAP message generated by ZSI.ServiceProxy and a respond from a Web Service when a Web Service method is invoked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some [documentation](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/zsi.html#SECTION0012200000000000000000) on the ServiceProxy class. The constructor accepts a `tracefile` argument which can be any object with a `write` method, so this looks like what you are after. Modifying the example from the documentation:

```
from ZSI import ServiceProxy
import BabelTypes
import sys

dbgfile = open('dbgfile', 'w')   # to log trace to a file, or
dbgfile = sys.stdout             # to log trace to stdout
service = ServiceProxy('http://www.xmethods.net/sd/BabelFishService.wsdl',
                       tracefile=dbgfile,
                       typesmodule=BabelTypes)
value = service.BabelFish('en_de', 'This is a test!')

dbgfile.close()
```